# aspell api documentation

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, aspell

where can i find aspell api documentation along with sample example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right here:

**[Writing programs to use ASpell](http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/6_Writing.html)**, specifically the first section entitled "Through the C API".

Comment: Thanks for this, but i want the entire documentation for the API's for all the classes relating to ASpell

Comment: when i use the code                                  AspellConfig* spell_config = new_aspell_config();  undefined reference displayed: ~/src/main.c:106: undefined reference to `new_aspell_config'

Comment: @iSight: The problem with open source libraries is that there isn't always full documentation available. (Well, maybe that problem isn't limited to open source...) The link above suggests looking in the source code for comments.

Comment: aspell_config_replace() function is also not working... same problem undefined reference.... wat can be the reason for this. I have added aspell.h header

Comment: The solution for the undefined reference is add -laspell in makefile.am file as  program_name_LDADD = \(if any linked file exist)         -laspell